# sscanf with hexadecimal negative value

Tags: c, hex, scanf, negative-number

I need to convert hexadecimal 4-digits values to decimal so I used ssscanf but it is not work on negative numbers...
For example,
    `int test;`
    `sscanf("0xfff6","%x",&test);`
return 65526 instead of -10.
How can I resolve that ?

Comment: What is sizeof(int) in your application? I'm going to bet it is 32 bit... If you used `short test;` you might get the answer you were expecting...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to do it manually. `x` conversion specifier performs a conversion from an `unsigned int` and it requires an argument of type pointer to `unsigned int`. For example with a cast:

```
unsigned int test;
int result;

sscanf("0xfff6","%x", &test);
result = (int16_t) test;
```

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the value of `test` is greater than 32k indicates it's a "long" integer (32 bit)...thus it doesn't see the sign bit. You would have to read the value into an unsigned short integer, then type cast it to a signed short, in order to see the negative value...

Answer (score 0):

I think the core issue is that you are assuming that an int is 16 bits, whereas in your system it appears to be larger than that.

Int is always signed, so the fact that it is reporting the result as 65525 proves that INT_MAX is greater than the 16 bit value of 36727.

Try changing your code from int text to short test and I suspect it will work.

Comment: Or not, as sscanf() will write a whole int to a short int storage!

Comment: I had not considered that, but course you are right.  Good catch.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because your integers are more than 16 bits wide so that `fff6` is indeed positive - you may need `fffffff6` or even wider to properly represent a negative number.

To fix this, simply place the following after the `scanf`:

```
if (val > 32767) val -= 65536;
```

This adjust values with the top bit set (in 16-bit terms) to be negative.