# Parsing negative hex values with boost spirit

Tags: boost-spirit

Why is this code not working

```
   std::string strVariant = "8000";
   short i16Value = 0;
   std::string::iterator it = strVariant.begin();
   if (qi::parse(it, strVariant.end(), qi::int_parser<short, 16>(), i16Value))
   {
      int a = 5;
   }
```

I would expect the value -32768. But parsing fails and i16Value contains 0x800.
I use boost 1.56.00

Answer (score 2):

This is failing on overflow check in Spirit internals. To fix this use `uint_parser` passing signed short as a template parameter:

```
qi::uint_parser<short, 16>()
```

**Update**: extract from the source code
Boost 1.60

*spirit\home\qi\numeric\detail\numeric_utils.hpp +142*

```
inline static bool add(T& n, Char ch, mpl::true_) // checked add
{
    // Ensure n *= Radix will not overflow
    typedef constexpr_int<T, boost::integer_traits<T>::const_max> max;
    typedef constexpr_int<T, max::value / Radix> val;

    if (n > val::value)
        return false;
```

Now:

```
val::value = 32767/16 = 2047 
n = 2048 (0x800) // 3 chars parsed
```

Comment: Can you add a little more authority to such a claim, perhaps by showing contradictory documentation and/or the failing line?

Comment: @sehe added failing line with some details.

Comment: +1 for the detail. I wouldn't call the solution a work around though. As the code shows, the limit is by design. The value just has to be in range, integer wrap around happens to be an implementation detail of the language, but not of the parser.

Answer (score 1):

This is by design.

Like with C++ literals, using iostream or POSIX functions¹ hexademal numbers are unsigned by definition.

You have to simply parse as unsigned and cast to the signed type if you require it.

Indeed, you can cast it implicitly by passing a `uint` attribute to a simple `hex` or `uint_parser<uint32_t, 16>`.

To help with attribute coercion rules you might let the conversion happen in the int parser itself, by specifying the "conflicting" type `uint_parser<int32_t, 16>`.

All of these are pretty subtle when embedded in your grammar definition, so I'd be sure to add a simple comment, if only to prevent people from "fixing" the bug :)

¹ see e.g. [sscanf with hexadecimal negative value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14802970/sscanf-with-hexadecimal-negative-value)